# Why is the default learning rate for Adadelta so low in Keras?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, keras

I have been training a model using the Adadelta optimizer for some time, and I noticed that it converges very, very slowly. Then I checked the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adadelta/), and to my surprise the default learning rate is **0.001**.

This is **1000 times smaller** than the learning rate of the "real" Adadelta optimizer. When I set it to 1, my model converged significantly faster. Why has Keras chosen to set the rate so low by default?

Comment: I would guess that it is just a conservative value to prevent overshooting

Comment: @JavierTG could be, but that's very model / problem specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into [TF source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ba63d9082a2265da91ec4daefecfa4cd47fcf07f/tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py#L38) you will find

```
def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-8,
               use_locking=False, name="Adadelta"):
    """Construct a new Adadelta optimizer.
    Args:
      learning_rate: A `Tensor` or a floating point value. The learning rate.
        To match the exact form in the original paper use 1.0.
      rho: A `Tensor` or a floating point value. The decay rate.
      epsilon: A `Tensor` or a floating point value.  A constant epsilon used
               to better conditioning the grad update.
      use_locking: If `True` use locks for update operations.
      name: Optional name prefix for the operations created when applying
        gradients.  Defaults to "Adadelta".
[...]
```

Developers are aware that the paper used `learning_rate=1.0`.
They put that notice there due to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8528).

[With the exception of SGD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e7433973375647699781a4d23487ebf2ce1639c7/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py), all other major optimizers have `learning_rate=0.001`, so it probably got the same value by coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Keras has enforced the same default values for each of the different optimizers. For most of the optimizers listed on [this page](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/), i.e.

- RMSprop
- Adam
- Adadelta
- Adagrad
- Adamax
- Nadam
- Ftrl

the default learning rate is always set to `0.001`.